# jQuery fly out

Tags: jquery

I wrote this jQuery script.
It works somewhat OK.  I want this fly out to close when the user mouse goes outside the fly out. How would I do that?

Here is the code below:

```
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#slick-box').hide();
            $('a#slick-toggle').mouseover(function() {
                $('#slick-box').toggle(400);
            }).mouseout(function(){
            $('#slick-toggle').hide();});
        });
    </script>

    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="slick-toggle" href="#"> toggle the box </a>
    <div style="position:relative;outline:1px dashed green;padding:10px;">
        <div id="slick-box" style="position:absolute;outline: 1px dashed hotpink; color:#fff; background-color:#000; opacity:0.8; filter:80;top:0px; left:0px ;">
            <h2>music name </h2>
            <p> This will be shown  and hidden</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>lorem ip sum loerm ip lorem ip sum lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ip sum loerm ip lorem ip sum lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ip sum loerm ip lorem ip sum lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ip sum loerm ip lorem ip sum lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ip sum loerm ip lorem ip sum lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ip sum loerm ip lorem ip sum lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ip sum loerm ip lorem ip sum lorem ipsum</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

[http://jsfiddle.net/dactivo/z2sWn](http://jsfiddle.net/dactivo/z2sWn/)/

It shows when you do mouseover the link, and it only disappears when you click in the document (it's what you've said in one comment).

```
$('#slick-box').hide();
$('#slick-toggle').mouseover(function() {
  $('#slick-box').show(400);
})
    $(document).click(function() {$('#slick-box').hide();});
```

Answer (score 2):

In the mouseout function, did you mean to use #slick-box instead of #slick-toggle?  Here's a live demo of that change http://jsfiddle.net/rchern/szSbF/

Comment: no, i want it to close only when the user click outside the expanded box

Comment: <script language="javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#slick-box').hide(); 
$('a#slick-toggle').mouseover(function() { 
  $('#slick-box').toggle(400); 
})}); 
 
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Is http://jsfiddle.net/pahnin/unGmT/ what you want?

When you mouse out the sleek box the sleek toggle will get hidden, and when you click outside the box gets hidden.

For that I have added another div called container which contains everything.